# Zendesk iOS - UIBarButtonItem does not display on Messaging instance ViewController

Tags: ios, zendesk

I've recently integrated Zendesk into my iOS project and have encountered a problem when I create  a `Messaging` UI instance that I then programmatically insert into a `UINavigationController`. I have the following code:

```
import AnswerBotSDK
import AnswerBotProvidersSDK
import ChatSDK
import ChatProvidersSDK
import MessagingSDK
import SupportSDK
import SupportProvidersSDK
import ZendeskCoreSDK

final class ZendeskController {
    init() {
        // ...Zendesk config stuff
    }

    func createInstance() -> UIViewController? {
        do {
            let requestConfiguration = RequestUiConfiguration()
            let messagingConfiguration = MessagingConfiguration()
            let answerBotEngine = try AnswerBotEngine.engine()
            let supportEngine = try SupportEngine.engine()
            let chatEngine = try ChatEngine.engine()
            
          
            let zendeskVC = try Messaging.instance.buildUI(
              engines: [answerBotEngine, supportEngine, chatEngine],
              configs: [messagingConfiguration, requestConfiguration]
            )

            return zendeskVC
        } catch let error {
            print("Error launching Zendesk: \(error)") //TODO: inform user
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to present the `UIViewController` generated by `createInstance()` in another controller of my choosing, I do the following:

```
if let zendeskSupportVC = ZendeskController().createInstance() {
    zendeskSupportVC.title = NSLocalizedString("Contact Us", comment: "Contact Us")
    let dismissBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(dismissSupportPage))

    zendeskSupportVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = dismissBtn
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: zendeskSupportVC)

    self.present(navigationController, animated: true)
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is that despite my creating of the `UIBarButtonItem` and my adding it as the `rightBarButtonItem` on the Zendesk view controller, it does not appear on the `UINavigationController` I embed it into when I go to present it modally. Has anybody else encountered this problem?

Comment: you are setting a navigation item rbefore a navigation controller, that's way it not show, you must add a right bar button item after the navigationController is set

Comment: @kjoe I just moved the UIBarButtonItem assignment to be after the view controller is embedded as the `rootViewController` of the `navigationController` and it still does not display.

Comment: I don't see the code where you added after the Navigation Controller is set